# Get the text of a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to save an old stored procedure into a string. When I use the following I do not get any line breaks.

```
SELECT @OldProcedure = Object_definition(object_id)
FROM   sys.procedures
WHERE  name = @ProcedureName
```

Any suggestions on how to get the stored procedure text with the line breaks?

I was thinking of using `sp_helptext`

Thanks

**Update**

I am copying and pasting the results from the results which will show me a single line.

As for the script as I am storing the results in a db field.  I am create a tool that will generate procedures on the fly, but I wanted to create a history of them.

**Update**

Turned out the Object_definition does what I want,  But for some reason when I copy it from the results I get a single line.

```
Declare @sql varchar(max) ;
SELECT @sql=Object_definition(object_id)
FROM   sys.procedures
WHERE  name = 'Test_QueryBuilder';

drop procedure Test_QueryBuilder
exec( @sql)
print @sql
```

Comment: How do you know there are no line breaks? Are you looking at this in SSMS? If so you just need to set the output to text instead of grid and it will show you the formatted text.

Comment: Why not just view them in SQL Server Management Studio and either "Script to" file or the query window?

Comment: sp_helptext is really the way to go. You'll get the exact definition of your procedure as it was/will be compiled on the server.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. If you want version control on your database objects, there are better approaches. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Anon.  It may.  Basically I built something to generate a stored proc.  I wanted to keep history all the procedures that it generated. Let me know if that falls into the XY problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Two ways:

```
select name, object_definition(object_id) 
from sys.procedures
```

or

```
select object_name(p.object_id), definition
from sys.sql_modules as m
join sys.procedures as p
   on m.object_id = p.object_id
```

Comment: This is the correct(er) answer, edited for correctness.

Answer (score 17):

I've recently come across the same question and made a quick and dirty script to get the definition of views, but the very same thing could also work for stored procedures and functions.

```
DECLARE @Lines TABLE (Line NVARCHAR(MAX)) ;
DECLARE @FullText NVARCHAR(MAX) = '' ;

INSERT @Lines EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_ProcedureName' ;
SELECT @FullText = @FullText + Line FROM @Lines ; 

PRINT @FullText ;
```

It simply uses `sp_helptext` as you suggested, grabs its output in a table variable and concatenates all the resulting lines into a text variable. It also uses the fact that each line in the `sp_helptext` result set includes the trailing new line character, so no need to add it here.

From there on, you just use the variable as you would do normally, print it, save to some table or do some manipulation on it. My particular use case was to build a helper stored procedure to drop a view and recreate it when modifying its underlying tables.

Comment: That works.  But you just need to add DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

Comment: Why that? How does that line fits in my example?

Answer (score 5):

I would highly recommend just using the "Script To" function in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

I have had great use of this in the past, when dealing with old objects like `Stored Procedures`.

Comment: Save the results or create the objects in a new DB?  What is your use case if you want to save the DB objects in a table?

Comment: yes .  that definitely works.  In this case I was automating something.

Comment: This does not work if you don't have permissions to view/script the stored procedures.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to log the text of a procedure every time it changes. You can do this automatically with a [DDL Trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx).  Unlike DML triggers, which fire on changes to the data, these will fire on changes to the database.

**Create a table to hold the audit log**

```
CREATE TABLE DDLAudit_Procedure_log (event_instance xml);
```

**Create a trigger to populate the audit log table**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg__DDLAudit_Procedure
ON DATABASE
FOR
  CREATE_PROCEDURE
 ,ALTER_PROCEDURE
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT DDLAudit_Procedure_log
        (event_instance)
  SELECT EVENTDATA();
END
```

**After your autogenerated procedures are created, check the log**

```
SELECT *
FROM DDLAudit_Procedure_log
WHERE event_instance.value('(//ObjectName)[1]','sysname') = 'MyAutoGeneratedProc'
ORDER BY event_instance.value('(//PostTime)[1]','datetime')
```

This is a simple example. You can examine the contents of [`EVENTDATA()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781.aspx) within the trigger to filter for specific tables. The MSDN help page has more detail.

Answer (score 1):

recommend to  "sp_helptext"   to get correct format